# How to encrypt mongo db password with jasypt?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, jasypt

**spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://user:secret@mongo1.example.com:12345,mongo2.e
 xample.com:12345/mydb?replicaSet=rsdb**

Here i want to encript the password(secret)with jasypt.So the url should be 
   like:

**spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://user:ENC(xIZhIV7nvOv5LqHfAKnvmjhyeecOT0lO)@mongo1.example.com:12345,mongo2.example.com:12345/mydb?replicaSet=rsdb**

but mongo is not understanding the password even if the jasypt encryption logic is already implemented.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got the solution:

Since it is not resolving encrypted value from url, we can put it in it's own property and then reference that property in the url.

**spring.data.mongodb.password=ENC(xIZhIV7nvOv5LqHfAKnvmjhyeecOT0lO)**

**spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://user:${spring.data.mongodb.password}@mongo1.example.com:12345,mongo2.example.com:12345/mydb?replicaSet=rsdb**